# How do I sort and delete records based on multiple columns and conditions?

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL database that takes items in a workflow, then adds a new record of them when they move to the next location (very poor design, I know... I didn't make it). But for example:

ID | JOB | LOCATION

1 | Ford | billed

2 | Ford | shipped

3 | Ford | delivered

4 | Dodge | ordered

5 | Chevy | ordered

So for this example, I want to search for any record where LOCATION is 'delivered', which Ford would match, then delete all other records where JOB is Ford but LOCATION is not 'delivered.'

There are over 93,000 records in this database because of how it was set up. So I'm trying to clear it out to hopefully speed up the custom app a previous employee wrote for the company I now work for.

Comment: Do you have anything that you've tried? Is it possible to make the app possibly do more work rather than doing this purely as a standalone query (not that this is unfeasible)? Some more context might be helpful to potential answerers.

Comment: You don't need to delete items because of performance. There are other (more powerful) ways to speed the app up. Using join conditions and indexes are one of these options.

Comment: I haven't really tried much as I'm still trying to wrap my head around how to search/ sort the thing. Knocking the database down from 93k records to something like 5k wouldn't cause a significant increase in speed? I'm still trying to find his code where he is searching for each job to see what method he is using.

Comment: A reduction from 93k to 5k is not particularly significant in database terms, where performance is often logarithmic: besides, what do you intend to do once you have 93k delivered orders in the system?  Moreover, the trail of events that arise during an order's progression through one's system might often be important for auditing and/or troubleshooting purposes, so it's rarely a good idea to completely purge them—at very least, you'll probably want to keep a backup somewhere.  I agree with @Tyr that you should probably look elsewhere for performance improvements.

Comment: I've made a backup already so I'm good on that front. Thanks for taking the time to explain that though, I guess I need to look through the web app's code a little harder and find where he is calling the database. As far as the 93,000 delivered issue, we are hopefully moving to a new system in the next few months so that shouldn't become a problem! Just trying to mitigate the issue till then!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the multiple-table `DELETE` syntax to perform a self-join:

```
DELETE a
FROM   myTable a JOIN myTable b USING (job)
WHERE  b.location  = 'delivered'
   AND a.location != 'delivered'
```

Comment: Wouldn't that delete any jobs that had not made it to delivered status?

Comment: I don't believe it would, as the first condition would not be met (`b.location = 'delivered'`)

Comment: @BlakeA.Norwood: As CollinD says, the requirement that `b.location = 'delivered'` (together with the join) ensures that only jobs for which such a record exists are deleted.

Comment: Oh, duh. Sorry! Let me test it out and I'll let y'all know how it goes.